# Merge rows in mysql based on condition

Tags: mysql

I am trying to merge the rows based on condition in mysql.

I have table as shown below :

[image]

Looking merge the row 1 into row 2 (where the attendance count is larger)

and need to shown the result as :

[image]

I was trying to divide the dataset into 2 parts using the below query

```
select 
a.student_id,a.school_id,a.name,a.grant,a.classification,a.original_classification,,a.consent_type
from (
select * from school_temp where original_classification='all' and availability='implicit')a
join(select * from school_temp where original_classification!='all' and availability!='implicit')b
on a.student_id = b.student_id and a.school_id=b.school_id and a.name=b.name
```

But unable to merge the rows and get total attendance count .
Please help me ,i am badly stuck in this

Comment: Why is the total attendance count 5228? 5227+3 = 5230.

Comment: Why is it only merging the second row? You have 4 rows where `original_classification!='all' and availability!='implicit'`.

Comment: Your query selects `a.original_classification`, but your desired result has `b.original_classification`.

Comment: extremely sorry !
total count should 5530.

It is getting merging to second row because second row is having the highest count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split this into two queries that you combine with `UNION`.

The first joins the `implicit` row with the row with the highest attendance among the explicit rows for each student. See [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql?rq=1) for how that works. Use `SUM(attendance_count)` to combine the attendances.

The second query in the `UNION` gets all the rows that don't have the highest attendance.

```
WITH explicit as (
    SELECT *
    FROM school_temp
    WHERE original_classification!='all' and availability!='implicit'
)

SELECT a.student_id, a.school_id, a.name, SUM(attendance_count) AS attendance_count,
    b.grant, b.classification, b.original_classification, b.consent_type
FROM school_temp AS a
JOIN (
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM explicit AS t1
    JOIN (
        SELECT student_id, school_id, name, MAX(attendance_count) AS max_attendance
        FROM explicit AS t2
        GROUP BY student_id, school_id, name
    ) AS t2 ON t1.student_id = t2.student_id AND t1.school_id = t2.school_id AND t1.name = t2.name AND t1.attendance_count = t2.max_attendance
) AS b ON a.student_id = b.student_id and a.school_id=b.school_id and a.name=b.name 
WHERE a.original_classication = 'all' AND a.availability = 'implicit'

UNION ALL

SELECT t1.*
FROM explicit AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT student_id, school_id, name, MAX(attendance_count) AS max_attendance
    FROM explicit AS t2
    GROUP BY student_id, school_id, name
) AS t2 ON t1.student_id = t2.student_id AND t1.school_id = t2.school_id AND t1.name = t2.name AND t1.attendance_count < t2.max_attendance
```

I've used a CTE to give a name to the subquery that gets all the explicit rows. If you're using MySQL 5.x, you'll need to replace `explicit` with that subquery throughout the query. Or you could define it as a view.